# What would be the easiest way to swap contents of two files in a git repository

Tags: git

What would be the easiest way to swap contents of two files in a git repository.

say contents of foo, bar needs to be reversed. I wouldn't be able to do a `git mv` here

Comment: Why not? Wouldn't `git mv foo foo-tmp && git mv bar foo && git mv foo-tmp bar` work?

Comment: it would, is there a better mechanism to achieve without the temp move. I am assuming not

Comment: No, there is no swap function in git, you need to either move/copy one file to a temporary file or recreate it afterwards. One way to avoid the temporary file is just to ask git to write the existing content into the other file, sort of like executing this command twice: `git show HEAD:path/to/file/a >path/to/file/b` though I'm not convinced this is safe for files that aren't textbased.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```sh
mv foo foo-tmp
mv bar foo
mv foo-tmp bar
git add foo bar
git commit -m "Swap foo and bar contents"
```

But I would echo Enrico Campidoglio's comment. There is no physical moving of files' content bits on your disk in method above nor with using `git mv`. In addition, using `git mv` may allow `git` some potential optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Since Git [tracks file paths in the index](http://shafiul.github.io/gitbook/7_the_git_index.html), in order to swap the contents of two files that are *already tracked* you have to modify their paths.

The easiest way to do that is by simply using a temporary file path in between:

```sh
git mv foo foo-tmp && git mv bar foo && git mv foo-tmp bar
```